# Jquery: Get row from cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row

I have a table where all my rows are like this:

```
<tr> 
    <td class="name">name1</td>
    <td class="type">type1</td>
    <td class="edit">
        <a href="edit" class="edit">edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need to disable the edit href for certain types.
So I need something like:

```
row = $('.mytable').find(row where .type value = type_with_no_edit) #this is where I need elp
row.find('a.edit').remove();
```

If the row was alwasy the first one, I would do:

```
row = $('.mytable tbody>tr:first')
```

but that's not always the case.

Comment: What do you mean "type_with_no_edit" ?

Comment: Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo-selector:

```
$('td.type:contains("type_with_no_edit")').siblings('.edit').empty();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XLwfs/

If you don’t want to empty the TD, just target the anchor and remove it instead.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a job for filter...

```
$('.mytable tr').filter(function() {
    return $("td.type", this).text() === "type_with_no_edit";
}).find('a.edit').remove();
```

That finds every row that has the text `type_with_no_edit` in the td with the class type and removes the td with `a.edit` that is a sibling.

Comment: Edited the code by adding () to text and stricter equality. :)

Comment: Doh!  Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: @limelights FYI `.text()` always return `string` so there is really no need for `===` in this particular case

Comment: @David yeah, I know but `===` is always a good practice. Read here why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Comment: That decision is very individual IMO. I’m just saying that in this case `==` and `===` makes no difference, hence my comment to the edit.

Comment: Of course , but I'm not really seeing a reason to go with the not as good way if I have the option to choose the right way. The point was to start enforcing a behaviour that is good practice and not lazyness, IMO. :D

Comment: @David That example is even worse. Youre relying on type conversion to convert the array object [] to a string. That is lying to yourself and your code. Fun example though! :)

Comment: @limelights no, Im just comparing `String('a')` with `'a'` using loose type comparison. Just one case where `==` is actually useful. But it’s all in my opinion of course. I personally don’t believe in saying "always use that" or "never use that" in a programming language.